# How to check wether a domain name exists in asp.net with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, lookup, domain-name

Is there a free/open source tool to verify wether a domain exists in c#?
I ve a textbox where my user can enter his domain name and list of radio buttons like .com,.net,.in etc...  Any suggestion..

Is there any webservice that does it?

**EDIT :**
 I need to check only the domain name availability.. Any ideas...

Comment: http://blog.flipbit.co.uk/2009/06/querying-whois-server-data-with-c.html (googling this took 10 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's built into the .net Framework:

```
var server = Dns.Resolve("www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: `Dns.Resolve()` (which is now deprecated) and `Dns.GetHostAddress()` (the replacment) lookup hosts, not domains. This won't work if there is no host entry for the domain, which is common for email-only domains. It will fail even though the domain exists. So this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool isDomainExist(string address)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    try
    {
        var r = request.GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

console.writeline(isDomainExist("https://stackoverflow.com"));
```